# New version of google app engine produces 404 error (PHP 5.5)

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a site running through google app engine on runtime environment php 5.5. I am trying to deploy a new version of the app (I do this by changing the version number in app.yaml, reference here: [Configuring with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig)) and deploying the app.

My current site can be reached via www.my-app-name.appspot.com (which works fine) and I should be able to view my new app version at www.2-dot-my-app-name.appspot.com, however I get a 404 error when trying to view version 2.

Version 1 and version 2 of my app are identical, the only difference being that version 2 has "2" as the version in app.yaml. Did I miss a step here? Is there something I need to do as far as configuration goes to view version 2? (*Note*: I do not want to make version 2 live, I just want to deploy it and test it to see if some changes work before making it live).

**Edit**: I tried testing to see what routing all traffic to version 2 of my app would do. In this case, version 2 of the app works but version 1 does not. It looks like when all traffic is routed to a particular version, that version is served up with the url "myappname.appspot.com". Any other versions are served using the url "version-dot-myappname.appspot.com". Anyone know how I can configure my app so that these urls work?

Comment: How many instances are running?  You'll need at least one per version.

Comment: Hey @snakecharmerb thanks for the tip. I actually just figured out what the issue was. Refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what the culprit was. I had a PHP configuration file that changed the header location to `'http://www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Though this type of configuration will work for your default app, it will not work when testing a new version because when testing a new version the routing cannot contain the leading 'www'. Hope this helps someone else down the line who encounters the same problem.

*Note:* If you use traffic splitting, users will not have any issues accessing your new version as long as your custom domain is mapped correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Routing via URL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/routing#routing_via_url) doc the address for your new app version should be `2-dot-my-app-name.appspot.com`, without the leading `www.`:

> ```
> https://version-dot-app-id.appspot.com
> http://version.app-id.my-custom-domain.com
>     Sends the request to an available instance of the given version of the default module.
> ```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be what's causing the routing error. Regardless of whether the leading www is present or not, the same 404 error occurs.

Comment: Do you see version 2 as `Serving` in the Developer Console? (see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/#versions)

Comment: Yes, the status of both versions of the app is "serving".

Comment: If you hover above that `2` it transforms into a link with that app version's URL, which you can follow. If you still get the 404 then you have to debug it, start by checking that version's logs in the logs viewer (select the version by navigating from the 1st drop-down list/button.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I still get a 404 error using this method as well. I've checked the logs, but they don't seem to exist since the site is just unable to get any requests from this URL. Strange.

Comment: It is the equivalent of me having typed "random-gibberish-here.appspot.com"

Comment: Maybe a glitch in deployment? I'd try to re-deploy, eventually after making a tiny change in addition to just the `app.yaml`' s version string (just in case).

Comment: I discovered what the issue was. Refer to the answer I posted to this question. Your initial answer of not including the leading 'www' helped me reach the solution. Thank you!